# jQuery Validate regex in HTML5

Tags: jquery, regex, html, validation, jquery-validate

Im using [jQuery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate a front end form. I ideally want the regex to be picked up from the HTML5 `pattern` attribute on the input field.

I have a working version using the following code:

```
function isUKPostcode(value){
  return /^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$/.test(value);
}

$.validator.addMethod("postcode", function(value, element){
  return this.optional(element) || isUKPostcode(value);
}, "Please enter a valid UK postcode");
```

But ideally I would like to set it up with simply:

```
<input id="Inputfield_user_first_name" class="postcode" name="user_first_name" type="text" maxlength="60" pattern="([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)">
```

The same way that attributes such as `required` and `maxlength` are automatically picked up by `$.validate()`

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Remove `$` from the `pattern`, HTML5 don't need the `^` and `$` anchors

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write a custom method.

You simply need to include [the additional-methods.js file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js). It includes the `pattern` method which will pickup the HTML5 `pattern` attribute automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I came up with the following code to check the `pattern` attribute and set a custom message during `validator.addMethod()`.

```
$o.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element){
  var pattern = $o(element).prop('pattern');
  if(!pattern || this.optional(element)){
    return true;
  }
  return new RegExp(pattern).test(value);
}, $o.validator.format("{0}"));

$o.validator.addClassRules("visible-postcode-input", {
  regex: "Please enter a valid UK postcode",
});
```